# replace a line of complex text within a number of files

Tags: command-line, awk, sed

I have a bunch of files named `Linux` in various sub-folders where the *whole line*

```
DSY_OS_Release=`lsb_release --short --id |sed 's/ //g'`
```

needs to be replaced with

```
DSY_OS_Release="RedHatEnterpriseWorkstation"
```

How can I achieve this using the command line?

I know this sounds like a duplicate question, but I could not find any answer which works for my rather complex string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to match the whole line, then just use

```
sed 's/^DSY_OS_Release=.*/DSY_OS_Release="RedHatEnterpriseWorkstation"/'
```

Depending on your `sed` implementation, you may use `sed -i '...' file`, or you may have to redirect to a new file and replace the original afterwards.

As for how to run this on a set of files:  If all files match a particular pattern, like `*.config`, then (assuming GNU `sed`):

```
find /some/path -type f -name '*.config' \
    -exec sed -i '...as above...' {} \;
```

Comment: thanks. actually  `find . -type f  -name 'Linux' -exec sed -i -- 's/^DSY_OS_Release=.*/DSY_OS_Release="RedHatEnterpriseWorkstation"/' {} +` did the trick.